# Dynamically update a key value inside ecs taskdef.json using shell script

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, shell, jq, ecs-taskdefinition

Below is my taskdef.json and want to update few values dynamically using shell script, I'm trying to use JQ but doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
{
    "containerDefinitions": [{
      "logConfiguration": [{
        "logDriver": "fluentd",
        "options": {
          "tag": "fluentd demo"
        },
        "secretOptions": [{
          "name": "fluentd-address",
          "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:region:aws_account_id:parameter:parameter_name"
        },
        {
            "name": "fluentd-name",
          "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:region:aws_account_id:parameter:parameter_name"
        }
    ]
      }]
    }]
  }
```

I want the region and aws_account_id to be updated dynamically instead of hardcoding the value directly inside the taskdef.json.Is there a way to update these value?

Comment: Yes, there's a way.  Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the use of `jq` is required or not, but you can simplly use `sed` to do the replacement:

```
region="us-east-1"
account_id="12345"

sed "s/region/${region}/g; s/aws_account_id/${account_id}/g" /path/to/taskdef.json
```

if you want to **permanently** change the  values in the input file, add `-i`:

```
sed -i "s/region/${region}/g; s/aws_account_id/${account_id}/g" /path/to/taskdef.json
```